# Error in getting calendar application

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am following the following link
  http://lovingandroid.blogspot.com/2011/08/retrieving-events-from-calendar.html
but getting exception at `calCursor.moveToFirst();`
I am working on emulator, What is solution of this???

Comment: The technique outlined by that blog post is undocumented and unsupported. Google has repeatedly told you to not use undocumented content providers. The supplied code will not work on all versions of Android. This content provider may not even exist on any given device. And Google may close down access to this content provider, as they have with others. Please use the Google Calendar GData API for manipulating a user's Google Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your cursor have no data

use like

```
    if(calCursor.getCount()>0)
    calCursor.moveToFirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

What exception did you get? Is it a null pointer exception? If yes, you might need to check calCursor is not null first before invoking its moveToFirst() method.